# Python Generator Returns Last Item

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, generator

I'm trying to loop through a CSV file and get an item from each row and insert it into the `QLineEdit` in the GUI.

When I click the button `self.nextAppointment` it fills the field in, but always with the very last row's email address in the CSV file. Subsequent clicks of the button do not appear to do anything.

I'm thinking that I'm not creating/using the generator correctly, but I am not sure.

How do I loop over the CSV file and get the fields I want returned so I can put that into the GUI on at a time for each row of the CSV.

Here is the relevant code:

```
self.nextAppointment.clicked.connect(self.nextFunction)

def nextFunction(self):
    self.emailGenerator = self.nextEmail()
    for email in self.emailGenerator:
        self.toField.setText(email)


def nextEmail(self):
    with open('assigned_appt_leads.csv', 'rb') as infile:
        rdr = csv.DictReader(infile, dialect='excel')
        for line in rdr:
            yield line['Email Address']
```

I've tested using the following and it gets the first email address, but pressing next does not change it to the next row's email address.

```
def nextFunction(self):
    self.emailGenerator = self.nextEmail()
    self.toField.setText(self.emailGenerator.next())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly looping and yielding.

What you are *not* doing is use the results correctly:

```
for email in self.emailGenerator:
    self.toField.setText(email)
```

will replace any previous textual value *each loop iteration*. This is why you see the last value only; all previous calls to `self.toField.setText()` succeeded, but where then overwritten again by the next iteration.

You need to *append* to the existing text in the `QLineEdit` widget instead. I suggest you use the `.insert()` method:

```
for email in self.emailGenerator:
    self.toField.insert(email + '\n')
```

If you wanted to assign items one by one to your field on user events, call `next()` on `self.emailGenerator` every time you need a new address:

```
self.toField.insert(next(self.emailGenerator, ''))
```

instead of looping over it. The above sample line sets the field to `''` if you've run out of email addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My goal is to only have 1 email listed at a time in the to field. Upon clicking the next button it'll grab the next row in the CSV file's email address, and other data too for other fields.

Comment: Updated the answer to provide you with a better option to do just that.

Comment: I've tried doing that and it doesn't clear the field and seems to only fetch the first line. What you're saying makes sense though.

Comment: Make sure you do *not* create a new generator every time you click the button. Keep the same generator object, a fresh generator starts from the beginning each time.

Comment: That was what I was doign, doh! Thank you so much for your help. I'm actually using `self.toField.insert(self.emailGenerator.next())` with `self.toField.clear()` above it.